# Pygame TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'Surface'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have only been learning Python for a couple weeks and this issue has me stumped. I'm trying to create a simple tower defense style game using Pygame. Been googling and researching for over 4 hours (the pygame docs website is down at time of posting, relying on a cached version). I'm sure it will end up being something trivially easy to fix but I am out of ideas.

I have the Tower class in one file and the main game loop in a different file. The image files are stored in a folder called "assets" which is in the same directory as the tower class and the main game loop. When I try to create a new tower, specifically load the tower's image, I get the error listed in the title.

I understand that I am somehow passing a "Surface" as the parameter, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where it is. I have the player select the type of tower they are building using the 1 or 2 keys, then look-up the corresponding image for that keypress, then place the tower where they click on the screen. The print statement immediately after the pygame event for clicking the mouse correctly lists "elf_tower.png" as the filename, but the print statement in the class's **init** says "". The class operates normally if I hard code the filename in for the image, but I doubt that is the best solution. I also tried just setting a variable to be "assets/" + tower_type but it similarly said it couldn't concatenate a Surface to a str.

Main file:

```
"""Homebrew tower defense game using pygame and object oriented programming.
This is a learning project"""
import pygame
from tower import Tower
from scaling import get_scaling_info

get_scaling_info()

def run_game():
    """Runs the game"""
    pygame.init()
    get_scaling_info()
    width, height = get_scaling_info()[1:]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN, 32)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Tower Defense")
    game_surface = screen.copy()

    def toggle_fullscreen():
        """Toggles between fullscreen and windowed mode"""
        if screen.get_flags() & pygame.FULLSCREEN:
            return pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.RESIZABLE)
        return pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    def update_display():
        """Update the game display"""
        scaling_info = get_scaling_info()[0]
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        for tower in Tower.towers:
            tower.draw()
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.scale(
            game_surface, (scaling_info.current_w, scaling_info.current_h)), (0, 0))
        pygame.display.update()

    run = True
    tower_type = 0
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    run = False
                if event.key == pygame.K_F11:
                    toggle_fullscreen()
                if event.key == pygame.K_1 or event.key == pygame.K_2:
                    tower_type = Tower.selection_dict[event.key]
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and tower_type != 0: #to prevent game from breaking if no tower selected.
                print(tower_type) #returns elf_tower.png which is the expected result
                mouse_x, mouse_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                Tower(tower_type, mouse_x, mouse_y).create_tower()

        update_display()

    pygame.quit()

run_game()
```

Tower class file:

```
"""Contains the class used to generate towers"""
import os
import pygame
from scaling import get_scaling_info

get_scaling_info()

class Tower:
    """Tower information"""
    selection_dict = {49:"elf_tower.png", 50:"dwarf_tower.png"} #pygame keypress of 1 corresponds to value 49, 2 to 50.
    towers = []
    def __init__(self, img, x, y, display_surface="game_surface"):
        x_scale, y_scale = get_scaling_info()[1:]
        self.img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets', img))
        print(self.img) # returns <Surface(40x40x32 SW)>
        self.x_coord = x * x_scale
        self.y_coord = y * y_scale
        self.display_surface = display_surface

    def create_tower(self):
        """Creates a tower of the selected type and scales to the correct size"""
        Tower.towers.append(Tower(self.img, self.x_coord, self.y_coord))
        print(Tower.towers)

    def draw(self):
        """Draws the tower on the screen using the specified image at coordinates x and y"""
        pygame.transform.scale(self.img, (32, 32))
        self.display_surface.blit(self.img, (self.x_coord, self.y_coord))
        print(self.img)

 #   def attack(self):
 #       """Causes the tower to attack enemies in range
 #       Not yet written"""
```

Image scaling file

```
"""Gets the scaling info used in the other modules of the game"""
import pygame

def get_scaling_info():
    """Gathers display info for scaling elements of the game"""
    pygame.init()
    display_info = pygame.display.Info()
    scaling_info = pygame.display.Info()
    x_ratio = display_info.current_w/scaling_info.current_w
    y_ratio = display_info.current_h/scaling_info.current_h
    return scaling_info, x_ratio, y_ratio
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong `Tower` construction (i.e. in `run_game`); the problem actually arises in the line

```
Tower.towers.append(Tower(self.img, self.x_coord, self.y_coord))
```

in the `create_tower` method, where you construct a new `Tower` using `self.img` as the first argument. In `__init__`, `self.img` is initialized to `pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets', img))`, which returns a `Surface`.

Likely, you want to store the `img` argument with which the `Tower` was constructed as another instance attribute, then use that in the `create_tower` method, e.g.:

```
class Tower:
    """Tower information"""
    selection_dict = {49:"elf_tower.png", 50:"dwarf_tower.png"} #pygame keypress of 1 corresponds to value 49, 2 to 50.
    towers = []
    def __init__(self, img, x, y, display_surface="game_surface"):
        x_scale, y_scale = get_scaling_info()[1:]
        self.img_file = img
        self.img = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets', self.img_file))
        print(self.img) # returns <Surface(40x40x32 SW)>
        self.x_coord = x * x_scale
        self.y_coord = y * y_scale
        self.display_surface = display_surface

    def create_tower(self):
        """Creates a tower of the selected type and scales to the correct size"""
        Tower.towers.append(Tower(self.img_file, self.x_coord, self.y_coord))
        print(Tower.towers)
```